# Composer Won't Run inside composer projects

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I'm having an issue with composer. When ever I run any composer command inside a project with a composer.json file even if I run composer init on an empty directory, once the process is complete it will no longer work.

The error I get is

```
 [JsonSchema\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException]
 file_get_contents(file://): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Its been working fine for ages and has just started doing this and i'm completely lost. I am also on windows.

I use laragon as well but I've tried installing composer on its own and still nothing

Comment: have you tried ```composer diagnose```?

Comment: It won't run inside the project, any composer command return the same error.

Comment: have you tried to download composer.phar to that folder and run it from there? ```php composer.phar diagnose```

Comment: I've included the composer.phar file and it seems to fix everything for that project, so thanks for that. Any idea why it won't work globally though?

Comment: maybe the file itself was corrupted, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the solution (or workaround) was:

1. download composer.phar https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
2. run it directly in the folder

more info on how to install composer:
https://getcomposer.org/download/